# Сторож и страж - есть ли различия?

Tags: значение-слов

Чем отличается сторож от стража?

Answer (score 1):

Сторож смотрит, чтобы никто не трогал, а страж смотрит за порядком.

Например:

- можно сторожить склад, но нельзя стоять на страже склада;
- собака может сторожить, но не может стоять на страже;
- можно быть стражем порядка, но нельзя быть сторожем порядка

Comment: Можно стоять на страже склада - склад с боеприпасами, например, охраняется стражами, а не сторожами. И у собак действия в этом же различаются - хозяйственная или военная охрана. У сторожа может быть обязанность дворника? Если да - то вот вам и сторож порядка.

Comment: @Нижегородец стоять на страже склада будет иметь иное значение от сторожить склад, и будет иметь смысл если у склада имеется определенный порядок за которым нужно следить.  Сторож конечно может быть дворником, а также отцом и мужем, и все это никак не пересекается.

Comment: Модератор на форуме - тот же сторож порядка.

Comment: Хотя с модератором я поторопился, это всё-таки - страж, а нет сторож.

Answer (score 1):

Существительные сторож и стража в принципе имеют одно и то же значение, различаются своим происхождением и стилистической функцией. По-русски слово звучало как сторож - с  полногласием -оро-. Его эквивалентом в старославянском языке является слово страж с неполногласием -ра-. 
Из словаря Фасмера:

> сто́рож род. п. -а, укр. сто́рож, др.-русск. сторожь, ст.-слав. стражь
>   φύλαξ (Супр.), болг. страж, словен. strȃžǝc, род. п. -žса, польск.
>   stróż. Праслав. *storžь, связано чередованием гласных со стерегу́.
>   Допуская начальное ts-, сравнивают с лит. sárgas м. "сторож,
>   охранник", лтш. sar̂gs – то же (Эндзелин, СБЭ 43 и сл.; Калима, FUF
>   21, 133 и сл.; Траутман, ВSW 257 и сл.) Отсюда сторо́жа "стража", укр.
>   сторо́жа, блр. сторо́жа, др.-русск. сторожа, ст.-слав. стража φυλακή,
>   κουστωδία (Остром., Супр.), болг. стража, сербохорв. стра̑жа, словен.
>   strȃža, чеш., слвц. stráž, польск. stróża, в.-луж. stróža,
>   н.-луж. stroža "стража, охрана"; см. Гуйер, LF 41, 430; Торбьёрнссон
>   2, 69; Ван-Вейк, AfslPh 36, 345. Сюда же сторожу́, сторожи́ть, укр.
>   сторожи́ти, сербохорв. стра́жити, стра̑жи̑м, словен. strážiti,
>   strȃžim, чеш. strážiti, слвц. strážit᾽, польск. stróżyć, в.-луж.
>   stróžić, н.-луж. strožyś. Формы страж, стра́жа заимств. из цслав.

https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-12785.htm

Слово страж употребляется в высоком стиле, в поэзии, в отвлеченном значении.
*На страже наших границ стоят люди в зеленых беретах.*
Слово сторож стилистически нейтральное, общеупотребительное.

"Сторож" - слово, часто встречающееся в повседневной современной речи, означает человека, который что-то охраняет и в обязанности которого входит необходимость периодически осматривать вверенный объект (сторожить, обходить охраняемую территорию"). "Страж" - слово, редко употребляемое в наши дни,  означает человека, который охраняет объект, стоя на одном месте, ассоциируется со стражей (часто помечается как архаизм), несущей военную службу (например, охраняет вход в царский дворец).

Comment: Страж революции - что охраняет? А страж правосудия? А тюремный страж разве охраняет? От кого и кого?

Comment: Это что за страж революции? Где Вы это взяли?
 Тюремный страж - архаизм, сейчас это охрана, как раз охраняет тюрьму. Страж правосудия тоже не слышала, если только "стоит на страже правосудия", т.е. охраняет правосудие - это отвлечённое понятие, не стоит у ворот, а стоит на страже порядка.

Comment: Не поняли. "Страж революции" - даже улица в НН так названа. У стража не только охрана была, но и многие другие обязанности. Страж и сторож - разные слова и разные понятия. Как служба и работа; как хозяйственная обязанность и военная обязанность. Почему словари не указывают на эти разницы? Почему пастух стережет, а волк сторожит?

Comment: Ну, значит, в революцию дали название - в значении "Тот, кто стоит на страже революции", охраняет её и её завоевания. Это тоже отвлечённое понятие "как верный 
 страж" - в высоком значении службы. Я и говорю: сторож - нейтральное бытовое, страж - высокое (служба на благо народа).

Comment: Сторож сторожит имущество, а страж сторожит не только имущество, но и порядок. У стража - долг; у сторожа - условия.

Comment: Ну, это то же самое: имущество-это бытовое, порядок - долг, высокое. Чувство долга - всегда высокое чувство

Comment: Блюститель порядка - страж, а сторож не может быть блюстителем порядка.

Answer (score 0):

Вот, что нарыл:  
У сторожа - хозяйственная работа: охрана, присмотр (смотритель маяка), пропускные обязанности (вахтёр). 
У стража - служебно-должностные обязанности (военная служба): охрана, присмотр, пропуск, караул, дозор, засада (вора сторожили не в том месте), соблюдение правопорядка, обязанности надзирателя.

Comment: Вы это в толковом словаре Кузнецова "нарыли"? Тогда лучше было процитировать, а не своими словами пересказывать, потому что там чуть аккуратнее сформулировано. Если у Вас другие источники, то не стесняйтесь их приводить (даже если это какая-то помойка.ру — там тоже могут попадаться "жемчужины в навозе").

Comment: Нет, не у Кузнецова, не знаю о таком словаре. Сам подумал и выложил, ушло на это около 10 минут. Собственная выкладка.

Comment: Если заниматься составлением собственного словаря, то есть другой способ. Нужно посмотреть в Нацкорпусе примеры употребления для этих двух слов и по ним определить значения и стиль. Это будет решение задачи. А потом сверить это решение с ответом (например, по Кузнецову или Ефремовой). Вот в словаре утверждается, что страж имеет стилевую пометку высок. Что Вы об этом думаете?

Comment: Дайте ссылку на Кузнецова.

Comment: Знать бы, что под "высок" имеется в виду. Наверное - высокопарно, то есть слово "страж" может использоваться в напыщенном изложении.

Comment: *Высок. (высокое) — для слов, передающих экспрессию  
приподнятости, торжественности.* Ссылка на словарь [вот](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6&all=x). Вводите слово и видите его в нескольких словарях. "Большой толковый словарь" и есть словарь Кузнецова.

Answer (score 0):

Сторож выполняет некую утилитарную функцию по охране имущества или ограниченной территории, и почти всегда делает это в рамках своих должностных обязанностей.

Страж - это не обязательно должность. Это вполне может быть призванием, не предполагающим материального вознаграждения.
Но в любом случае, страж, как правило, защищает нечто больше, чем просто товарно-материальные ценности. Он может защищать мораль, безопасность, порядок, государственность и т.д.

Термин "страж" обычно имеет не просто позитивную, но и весьма уважительную коннотацию (за исключением случаев, когда это слово сознательно используется в ироничном контексте, например: *"вместо того, чтобы ловить бандитов, стражи порядка гоняют бабушек в переходах"*).
Должность сторожа такой коннотацией, как правило, не обладает.